# C# How to make a control like Pivot Table

Tags: c#, pivot-table

I want to create myself a pivot table control like in excel. I know that there is commercial library to do this, but it is too expensive with me.

I don't know what is the term of this type of control (the circle in the picture), which can help me to define sum, count, average, ... for the field I want to calculate.

Anyone know the term so that I can google ?

Thank you so much

[image]

Comment: Hi user3819222, can you please tag your platform ? is it supposed to work with XAML-platforms (WPF, Universal), or are you using WinForms ? In terms of Winforms, you show a **CheckedListBox** with a **ContextMenu** on top.  The menu options are events in your program, that involve operations in the **Items** list of your CheckedListBox.

Comment: Hi, I would like to work in winform

Answer (score 0):

I have found a library that have community licence (like microsoft visual studio), which can do all these for me.

https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/pivot-grid/getting-started

They have some limititations if you want to use it free. It is ok for my personal use.

Best Regards,